# Backfire.js Model not getting attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase, backfire

Using backfire (backbone.js and firebase.js) im having issues getting my data into the model.

Im trying to populate a model once the user has authenticated (so i know which user to get, duh)

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  firebase: '',

  setUser: function(uid){

    this.firebase = new Backfire.Firebase('https://app.firebaseio.com/' + uid);
  }
});
```

Once I have a successful login I create a new model and call setUser with the ID returned from firebase auth (simpleuser:10). Then I call userModel.fetch() which only updates the attributes not the rest of the model.

```
userModel.fetch(): undefined
userModel.attributes
    Object {0: "simplelogin:10", 1: "Master Blaster", 2: "Joe Blow", 3: ..."}
```

I cannot call .get('title') //should be related to element '1' above.

Something is wrong somewhere, I didnt set the data initially using Backfire.js.

Suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks everyone

**EDIT**
Seems the way im storing my data in firebase will cause lots of issues. Im nesting lots of data. That needs to be resolved first. **SIGH**